# Extend Div to bottom of page, starting from absolute position

Tags: html, css

First, I'd like to say that I have no experience with HTML or CSS so bear with me here.

I'm trying to have a Logo, content, then footer. The Logo has a background that overlaps with content, and footer has a background that overlaps with footer aswell.

This pic might explain better: http://picpaste.com/help-vXUqWlZ8.png

HTML Code: http://pastebin.com/0ZWCB9jU
CSS Code: /w7Ugu78Z <-- also pastebin, but I can't post entire link due to spam prevention.

The problem is that, there's an extra space at the bottom of the page that I can't remove.

Would really appreciate any help.. I tried googling but the solutions I found I failed to get it to work.

Best Regards,
Essam.

Comment: Post your source in http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Thanks for that. Pastebin didn't seem like the best choice. http://jsfiddle.net/bP3zK/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want the footer to remain at the bottom of the page.

I think this is what you're looking for: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: I don't just want it to remain at the bottom of the page, I need it to start at the end of the content area.. I tried having the footer sticking to bottom of page, although that solves the extra un-needed area at the bottom, It doesn't start where I want it to. Hope that made any sense.

Comment: Yes... I understand. This method here will cause the content area to expand, forcing the footer to the bottom... you want the *footer* section to expand instead.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that. I should've read it more carefully the first time. This worked out fine, when I zoom in or out it acts a little weird but by default it's good. Thanks for that.